# jQuery .change() not happening when dynamically adding content to a form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

This code populates a form from an API.

```
$('#shipper_search').click(function(){

    var searchBy = $('#shipper_search_by').val();
    var searchFor = $('#shipper_search_for').val();
    var warehouse = $('#warehouse').val();

    $.get('index.php?p=api&r=json&c=location&m=find&d=' + searchBy + '/' + searchFor + '/shipper/' + warehouse  , function(data, status){

        data = $.parseJSON(data);

        $('#shipper_name').val(data['body'][0]['location_name']);
        $('#shipper_address1').val(data['body'][0]['address1']);
        $('#shipper_address2').val(data['body'][0]['address2']);
        $('#shipper_city').val(data['body'][0]['city']);
        $('#shipper_state').val(data['body'][0]['state']);
        $('#shipper_zip').val(data['body'][0]['zip']);
        $('#shipper_country').val(data['body'][0]['country']);

        $('#shipper_contact_name').val(data['body'][0]['contact_name']);
        $('#shipper_contact_phone').val(data['body'][0]['phone']);
        $('#shipper_contact_fax').val(data['body'][0]['fax']);
        $('#shipper_contact_email').val(data['body'][0]['email']);

    });

});
```

Each time a field changes in that section the following code is supposed to run:

```
$('#shipperinfo').find('input:text').change(function(){

    var valid = 0;

    if($('#shipper_name').val().length > 0){
        valid++;
    }

    if($('#shipper_address1').val().length > 0){
        valid++;
    }

    if($('#shipper_city').val().length > 0){
        valid++;
    }

    if($('#shipper_state').val().length > 0){
        valid++;
    }

    if($('#shipper_zip').val().length > 0){
        valid++;
    }

    if($('#shipper_country').val().length > 0){
        valid++;
    }

    if(valid == 6) {

        $('#shipper_ok').removeClass('hide');

    } else {

        $('#shipper_ok').addClass('hide');

    }

});
```

When a user manually types the information into the field, the second function works perfectly. When, however, they use the search feature to populate the form the .change() doesn't seem to happen.

I've been searching for an age as to why, and I'm relatively new (~4 days) to jQuery/JS so I'm not sure how to begin to resolve this. Any suggestions or ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change() is not triggered when JavaScript updates the fields.

Easiest solution is to have one of the elements trigger the change method

```
$('#shipper_contact_email').val(data['body'][0]['email']).trigger("change");
```

or

```
$('#shipper_contact_email').val(data['body'][0]['email']).change();
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. :) I went with the first option.

When I'm allowed I'll accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

change does not work if you change its value dynamically, you have to do it manually.

i would do it like this.

```
$('#shipper_search').click(function(){

var searchBy = $('#shipper_search_by').val();
var searchFor = $('#shipper_search_for').val();
var warehouse = $('#warehouse').val();

$.get('index.php?p=api&r=json&c=location&m=find&d=' + searchBy + '/' + searchFor + '/shipper/' + warehouse  , function(data, status){

    data = $.parseJSON(data);

    $('#shipper_name').val(data['body'][0]['location_name']);
    $('#shipper_address1').val(data['body'][0]['address1']);
    $('#shipper_address2').val(data['body'][0]['address2']);
    $('#shipper_city').val(data['body'][0]['city']);
    $('#shipper_state').val(data['body'][0]['state']);
    $('#shipper_zip').val(data['body'][0]['zip']);
    $('#shipper_country').val(data['body'][0]['country']);

    $('#shipper_contact_name').val(data['body'][0]['contact_name']);
    $('#shipper_contact_phone').val(data['body'][0]['phone']);
    $('#shipper_contact_fax').val(data['body'][0]['fax']);
    $('#shipper_contact_email').val(data['body'][0]['email']);

    //here what i call it manually
    $('#shipperinfo').find('input:text').change();

});

});
```

and bind that function to that event.

```
function change_callback()
 {
    var valid = 0;

    if($('#shipper_name').val().length > 0){
        valid++;
    }

    if($('#shipper_address1').val().length > 0){
        valid++;
    }

    if($('#shipper_city').val().length > 0){
        valid++;
    }

    if($('#shipper_state').val().length > 0){
        valid++;
    }

    if($('#shipper_zip').val().length > 0){
        valid++;
    }

    if($('#shipper_country').val().length > 0){
        valid++;
    }

    if(valid == 6) {

        $('#shipper_ok').removeClass('hide');

    } else {

        $('#shipper_ok').addClass('hide');

    }

}

$('#shipperinfo').find('input:text').on('change', change_callback);
```

try it and let me know if this work for you.

Comment: This would likely work, but adding the .trigger('change') took less code since I only need to trigger the change for the last element I update and it will test the others. Thanks for this though, it's always helpful to know more than one way to do something, I'm sure I'll find this useful in the future as (sadly) jQuery and I will be spending more time together than I would like.